# get url and add to href in jQuery or JS

Tags: jquery

on a page i have a link

```
<a href="/_l/R/Contact.aspx" id="ctl00_SPLinkbutton1"><span class="ms-splinkbutton-text">Contact</span></a>
```

I would like to get the current url of the page i'm on and add it to the href.

So if I am on `http://mysite.com` when I click the link contact above I would go to the page `http://mysite.com/_l/R/Contact.aspx?source=http://mysite.com`.

Any ideas on how to achieve that in jQuery or JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rx8g3/1/),

```
$("#ct100_SPLinkbutton1").click(function(e) {  
  e.preventDefault();
  document.location.href = $(this).attr("href") + "?source=" + document.location;
})
```

**UPDATED**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/_l/R/Contact.aspx" id="ctl00_SPLinkbutton1">
    <span class="ms-splinkbutton-text">Contact</span>
</a>
<script>
$('a#ctl00_SPLinkbutton1 span').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.location.href = $(this).attr("href") + "?source=" + document.location;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Get this code to your own html page and test, however same code is not working in fiddle, may there is issue in the fiddle in my network.

Comment: thanks for your help i ended up using thi: jQuery("a#ctl00_SPLinkbutton1").live("click", function(e){ 
          e.preventDefault();
          document.location.href = $(this).attr("href") + "?source=" + document.location;
        });

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ct100_SPLinkbutton1').click(function() {    
  window.location += $(this).attr('href') + '?source=' + window.location;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using 
`document.referrer`  on your next page to get the source url of your previous page